# Make a ssh tunnel for a remote folder and work on it

Tags: ssh

I am facing the problem that I have to work on some files which I can access only through `ssh`. Hence I have to work on them locally, then push them to the server with `scp` and test them there. I am wondering if it is possible to open a ssh tunnel and open some remote folder in a native system. In other words, I log in using the ssh client:

`ssh -L 1337:localhost:1337 name@server.com`

What I want to do next is to open this using my systems' folder viewer. On Ubuntu I have an ability to browse a remote server:

[image]

However, if I try co connect, the connection got refused, and I see the following message in the terminal:

`channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused`

Is there a way to handle it? Because if I were able to open the remote folder in my native system, I would be able to open this folder somewhere in a code editor and modify the data without the pain of `scp`.

Comment: What kind of service is listening on port 1337? If it's just SSH – what's the purpose of the tunnel instead of just pointing the ssh:// URL directly to the same server?

Comment: nobody is listening on port 1337. The purpose of the tunnel is to work on remote files as if they were local, without the use of `scp`.

Comment: That's completely not what a `-L` tunnel does, though...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an SSH tunnel for that; you can use the SSH connection you already have:

```
ssh://name@server.com
sftp://name@server.com
```

SSH tunnels themselves do not give you access to *files* – their purpose is to provide access to TCP services. An `-L` tunnel configured to connect to `localhost:1337` is completely useless if the server has nothing listening there. (And if the server did have SSH listening on port 1337, using a tunnel wouldn't gain you anything as you'd only be tunneling SSH-inside-SSH...)